# C# Compiling User Supplied Code And Using

Tags: c#, scripting, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

What I'm trying to do is allow a user to write a method in a textbox and have my code call that method. This will eventually be used in a demo applet for optimization given a goal function.

So I've been working with a sample console application but I'm having trouble. I've checked stack overflow and codeproject and other sources, and have got to the point where I can compile the code. But I'm lost at how to call it and only access a method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CodeCompilerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            //parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            //parameters.OutputAssembly = "Output.dll";

            string SourceString = @"
                                   using System;
                                   using System.Collections.Generic;
                                   using System.Text;

                                   namespace testone 
                                   {
                                        public class myclass
                                        {
                                            public double Main()
                                            {
                                                return testd(5,8);
                                            }

                                            public double testd(double a, double b)
                                            { 
                                                return a+b;
                                            } 
                                        } 
                                    }";

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, SourceString);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line number " + CompErr.Line + ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber + ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Assembly mAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type scripttype = mAssembly.GetType("myclass");
            Object rslt = new Object();
            Object[] argin = {5, 8};
            //rslt  = scripttype.GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, null);
            rslt = scripttype.InvokeMember("Main", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public |BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
            Console.WriteLine(((double)rslt).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried different combinations on how to call the Invoke on the method and keep getting errors.
What I want to be able to do is have the user define a function like this:

```
public double funcname(double x, double y)
{
    return x+y;
}
```

And then I could just call funcname directly.
If this is not doable, I'll take what I can get at this point.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the namespace in the `GetType` call.
(Or remove the namespace from the source)

You may prefer to call `GetTypes()` and see all of the types defined in the assembly instead.

Comment: So that allows me to call the function using the Invoke method. Do you know of a way to just call it like "testd(5,8)"?  The eventual hope is to the user supplied function as a delegate to dll.

Comment: Another useful resource that more or less says the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698870/accessing-class-and-function-after-compiling-compiledassembly

Comment: @Tim: Call `GetTypes()` and find a type that has the function you're looking for.

Comment: Seems there was some confusion. I can call testd() using the invoke method. But I was wondering if there was a way to have it accessible in the main where i can just say double x = testd(a,b).

Comment: @Tim: No; the compiler cannot know what `testd` is.  Even `dynamic` isn't quite enough for that.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I thought it would not be able to, but I'm happy with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this article will help you to access the method directly through using interfaces
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26312/Dynamic-Code-Integration-with-CodeDom

Maybe the below is not relevant directly to your request, but I believe that you need to use Activator to create an instance of the class so you can call the `testd` method
I mean your code defined has no object, just class definition.
Also I used `GetTypes()[0]` because `GetType()` didn't work for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CodeCompilerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            //parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            //parameters.OutputAssembly = "Output.dll";

            string SourceString = @"
                                   using System;
                                   using System.Collections.Generic;
                                   using System.Text;

                                   namespace testone 
                                   {
                                        public class myclass
                                        {
                                            public double testd(double a, double b)
                                            { 
                                                return a+b;
                                            } 
                                        } 
                                    }";

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, SourceString);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line number " + CompErr.Line + ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber + ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Assembly mAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
            Type scripttype = mAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
            Object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(scripttype);
            double  rsltd = 0.0;
            Object[] argin = { 5.0, 8.0 };
            rsltd  =(double) scripttype.GetMethod("testd").Invoke(myObject,argin);
          //  object rslt = new object();
           // rslt = scripttype.InvokeMember("testd", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null);
       Console.WriteLine(rsltd.ToString());
       Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```